Can jinns be behind these reincarnation cases?
So I've been reading a lot of these cases where the 'reincarnated individual' makes a couple of statements about their 'past life', and a group of researchers go out and validate their statements. One interesting case is definitely when this little boy gives 55 accurate statements about his past life as a hollywood background actor. You can check out the work of Ian Stevenson for more clarification.
Could this be the work of the jinns? Is it possible for the jinn to feed these families such information, and appear in their dreams? I believe they also use hypnosis to figure this out, could it be because of the magic in it?
